# wrong redirect after sign up fail devise 2.0 and rails 3.2.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, devise

I have this devise routes in **routes.rb** file:

```
 app::Application.routes.draw do
 scope ":locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/  do
         devise_for :users, :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "registrations" } do
         delete "/logout" => "devise/sessions#destroy"
         get "/login" => "devise/sessions#new"
         get "/sign_up" => "devise/registrations#new"
         get "/settings" => "devise/registrations#edit"
         get "/recover_password" =>  "devise/passwords#new"
         get "/confirm_account" =>  "devise/confirmations#new"
        end
      end
   match '*path', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}")
   match '', to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}")
 end
```

I'm using `http://localhost:3000/es` for spanish language and `http://localhost:3000/en` for english language in project.

If I go to `http://localhost:3000/en/sign_up` and I try create a new user and fail, the redirect go to `http://localhost:3000/en/users`

This redirection is wrong because If I try change language in my switch language, I redirect in browser to users#index action.

I need that redirect go to `http://localhost:3000/en/sign_up` or `http://localhost:3000/es/sign_up`

I have overrided the **devise action create** in **registrations_controller.rb** with

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  def create
    build_resource

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_in(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with({}, :location => after_sign_up_fails_path_for(resource))
    end
  end

  private
  def after_sign_up_fails_path_for(resource)
   sign_up_path
  end

end
```

**The problem here is that I can not see the errors in fields form. I mean the app does not show the errors in the form fields. devise_error_messages are empty.**

**How can I fix this trouble?**

Thank you very much

Comment: Have you declare all the helper in your helper.rb file

Comment: Thank you @urjitrajgor can you write a example for fix this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(My answer was wrong - I changed it)

I think instead of redirecting on failure:

```
respond_with({}, :location => after_sign_up_fails_path_for(resource))
```

you want to stay on the same page with the same failed resource:

```
render :action => 'new'
```

although the original line should have the same effect:

```
respond_with resource
```

Comment: Thank you Cezary Baginski, but I have checked with `sign_up_path(resource)` inside private method `after_sign_up_fails_path_for` and I get a routing error for me this code not works fine :(